# image is not getting loaded in view

Tags: iphone

I have created 2 views named "FirstView" and "SecondView".SecondView's nib file has an UIImage view object as its IBOtlet.Now I am getting an UIImage object from some FirstViewController's method.Now I am setting the SecondViewController's imageView property with that image and then I am pushing my SecondView Controller's object in Navigation Controller.The SecondView gets loaded but that image is not shown in that view. The code is as follows:.....

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo
{
   [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

   SecondViewController *secondView=[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

   secondView.imageView.image=img;

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];  
}
```

Comment: is "img" set to a valid image at this point?

Comment: Yes it is a valid image.

Answer (score 1):

The view is probably not loaded from the nib yet. So the IBOutlets are not hooked up already. In `firstView`, set a property on `secondView`, and in the `viewDidLoad` method of this secondView, set the `imageView.image` to this property.